# Why is FindNext is so slow?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I'm simply trying to loop over a bunch of cells and mark them as dirty (with excel calculation set to manual) so that I can then quickly tell excel to recalculate *just* those cells and their dependencies.

For some reason though, excel's `.FindNext` method is SO slow that it's actually far faster just to call `Application.CalculateFull()`. How is this so slow?

The below solution almost exactly matches the Microsoft recommended solution for "FindAll": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e4x1k99a.aspx

```
app.Calculation = Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;
DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in app.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets)
{
    Excel.Range uncalculatedCell = sheet.Cells.Find("[Wait]", 
        LookIn: Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, 
        SearchOrder: Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, 
        SearchDirection: Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, MatchCase: true);
    if (uncalculatedCell == null) return;
    Excel.Range first = uncalculatedCell;
    do
    {
        uncalculatedCell.Dirty(); //Can be commented out, doesn't impact time
        uncalculatedCell = sheet.Cells.FindNext(After: uncalculatedCell);
    } while (uncalculatedCell.AddressLocal != first.AddressLocal);
}
TimeSpan markDirty = (DateTime.UtcNow - start); //16 seconds for 300 results?!
app.Calculate(); //Trigger recalculation
TimeSpan recalculate = (DateTime.UtcNow - start) - markDirty; //~2 seconds
//app.CalculateFull() //~4 seconds depending on what else is in the sheet
```

For example:

If there are 0-5 matching cells in a workbook, this routine is completing in about 0.05 seconds (50 milliseconds). Great! But if there are approximately 300 cells that need to be marked dirty, this routine completes in about 16 seconds. There's no reason for this. We expect the need to identify thousands of these cells at times.

After marking the cells dirty, running `Calculate()` correctly only recalculates those cells (and any volatile cells), and their dependencies. This `Calculate()` is faster than calling `RecalculateFull()`, but not taking into account the time required to find the desired cells and mark them as dirty (which I expected to be almost instantaneous.)

Is there a way to identify only the cells that need recalculating and getting them updated faster than this?

Comment: Note that I need to use XlLookAt.xlPart because most of the cells in question contain a message such as "[Wait] 3.5 seconds"

Comment: Someone suggested that simply the overhead of making that many interop calls might be what's so slow. Is there a way to batch them together (like putting together a VBA macro and remote executing it in excel?)

Comment: A similar question was asked almost 2 years ago, but wasn't as clear and is unresolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053210/why-is-searching-multiple-sheets-so-slow